# Access object on another form with the form as a variable

Tags: forms, delphi, methods, procedure, dynamicobject

I'm writing a program in Delphi which includes creating the same dynamic object on multiple forms (never simultaneously), and then a procedure in another unit writes certain text to it.

How the object (TMemo) is created:

```pascal
memHulp := TMemo.Create(frmHome);
with memHulp do
begin
  Parent := frmHome;
  Top := 208;
  Left := 88;
  Height := 98;
  Width := 209;
  ReadOnly := True;
end;
```

The properties aren't that important, it's just to show the creation of the object and how it is referred to.

Now, I need to read certain text into the memo from a text file, which there is no problem with, but the problem comes when there are different forms involved that all use that same self-defined procedure.

It's easy to say `frmHome.memHulp.Lines.Add()` in this particular case, but when I need it to display the text on the memo **named exactly the same in all cases, but on a different form,** I'm having some trouble.

The `frmHome` part needs to be a variable. So I tried this:

```pascal
var 
  Form: TForm;
begin
  Form := Application.FindComponent('frmHome') as TForm;
end;
```

That doesn't warn me or give an error, but as soon as I try to say `Form.memHulp.Lines.Add()`, it does not work, and I understand that it probably doesn't have any properties for `Form`, but how do I make it look at the correct place? I need to be able to tell the program to look on whichever form name I pass as a parameter into the `FindComponent()` part.

If this is completely not possible, please suggest other solutions to achieve the same.

Comment: Create a base class for your forms, e.g. `TFormWithMemHulp`, which has this property. Then, make all of your forms which should support it inherit from that class instead of directly inheriting from `TForm`. Then, you do `Form: TFormWithMemHulp` and access the property.

Comment: "_It does not work_" can't be more imprecise. Also `frmHome` **is already** a variable - go look where it is declared. You didn't even look if `Form` has a value of `nil`. Also you should enumerate thru all your forms by `for i:= 0 to Screen.FormCount- 1 do if Screen.Forms[i].Name= 'frmHome' then ...;` and keep in mind that there may be no match either.

Comment: From where is this procedure of yours being called? If it is prom any method that belongs to this specific form then you could use `Self` as input parameter to your procedure and by doing so pass the reference to the form that called the said procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form.memHulp` doesn't work because `Form` is a plain vanilla `TForm` pointer, and `TForm` doesn't have a `memHulp` member.  You could use `Form.FindComponent('memHulp')` instead, since you are assigning the `TForm` object as the Memo's `Owner`, but that would require you to assign a `Name` to the Memo, eg:

```pascal
memHulp := TMemo.Create(frmHome);
with memHulp do
begin
  Parent := frmHome;
  Name := 'memHulp';
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, since you say you are creating only 1 Memo object at a time, you could simply make `memHulp` be a global variable in some unit's `interface` section, and then you would have direct access to it without having to hunt for it.

Comment: Thank you Remy, but before I can call `Form.FindComponent('memHulp')` I need to find the correct form name first. How will I do that?

Comment: @WilmerKluever You already know how - `Application.FindComponent()` will work fine for any `TForm` that is owned by `Application` and has a `Name` assigned to it. Or, loop through `Screen.Forms` , like [AmigoJack described to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803589/68805042?noredirect=1#comment121595658_68803589).

Comment: OK I think I am very close now. Only hiccup left is `Form.findcomponent('memHulp').Lines.Add(sLine);` produces error ''TComponent' does not contain a member named 'Lines' at line ...' I think I have to somehow tell it what component its working with, but how?

Comment: @WilmerKluever Type-cast the `TComponent` to `TMemo`, eg: `TMemo(Form.FindComponent('memHulp')).Lines.Add(sLine);`